# Firefox 14 on Ubuntu gets stuck connecting

Tags: python, ajax, firefox, ubuntu, xmlhttprequest

I have a custom application written in python on Ubuntu.  It's a bit hairy to unwind all the pieces to get to a reduced question to ask (will post more if I get there), but I have a few things to ennumerate.  After trial-and-error, I have backed this problem off to just firefox 14.

1. Things were fine on firefox 13, firefox 14 was updated on Ubuntu, and stuff broke. (this is not uncommon, but I can't find this problem referenced anywhere yet)
2. We go to a page in our webservice and reload, 10 or so times, and then the reload hangs, spinning with "Connecting" in the status bar.
3. Connections on Firefox are getting consumed by XHRs.  Increasing the max connection setting in firefox works around the issue.  Basically we open up an XHR that in chrome, I can't even see, but in firefox shows with a spinner in firebug.  That XHR seems to stay open across page reloads, and eventually consumes the open connections to the site.
4. After a couple minutes or so, a connection frees up and the load goes through.

Has anyone seen this?  Is there a proper way to release the connection?  All other browsers tried are not having this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Firefox 15 beta has solved the problem.  If I find anything in the FF release notes, I'll update the answer.

There is now a Firefox bug to track this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779637).

Answer (score 1):

I have many tests in my rails application that worked ok before I updated to firefox 14.01. After that, Firefox browsers opens and just hangs there. I had to switch to Chrome (downloaded driver from Google). If of any help, this is how I initialize driver in ruby:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'll update the question a bit with more findings. Switching to chrome fixes the problem, however I'm not really testing firefox at that point. :)